# Why do my sub domains point to other sub domains when I disable a site?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, apache2, lets-encrypt, digital-ocean

I have a personal server and I use many sub-domains on it.
Each sub domain has its own unique SSL cert setup with **LetsEncrypt**.
Each sub domain has its own vhost file under `/etc/apache/sites-available/`
Each sub domain has its own A record and NS record that point to my server.

For some reason, if I disable one of my subdomains (e.g. `sub1.domain.com`) using the a2dissite command, and then try to go to that site in a web browser, I get an error saying:

> **sub1**.domain.com uses an invalid security certificate.
>   The certificate is only valid for **sub2**.domain.com
>   Error code: SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN

I have verified that the VHOST files do use their appropriate SSL files. And the VHOST files also have the appropriate server name, including the sub domain part.

If I add an exception to the above error, as is an option, I am presented with another one of my subdomains but the URL stays the same as the one that's disabled.

Why does my server point me to a completely different sub-domain when I disable the site? I would think that it would just say it can't be reached, but instead it redirects me to another one of my sub-domains and I'm not sure how to control that.

Answer (score 2):

First configured vhost has the highest priority and can be seen as the **default** or primary server. That means that if a request is received that does not match one of the specified ServerName directives, it will be served by this first .

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html

In your case sub1.domain.com points to your web server, but web server has no vhost configured that would match the domain. Instead content and SSL cert for **default** domain are served.

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking it was probably a "feature". Is there a configuration to disable this and just have it show unavailable instead of serving the next in line?

Comment: @Frantumn Someone else has asked [that question](https://serverfault.com/q/444217/126632) here before. You may be interested to read it.

Comment: I would suggest the HTTP 403 approach over default Apache page: https://serverfault.com/questions/114931/how-to-disable-default-virtualhost-in-apache2

Comment: So, do I make a new vhost file, put this in it `<VirtualHost _default_:*>
    <Location />
        Deny from all
        Options None
        ErrorDocument 403 Forbidden.
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>`  and then enable it?

Comment: @Frantumn Why do you want to loose these visitors? You could redirect them to your website.

Comment: I use my server for 99% personal reasons. I don't want visitors unless I share a URL specifically with friends / family.  Right now, if I visit a subdomain that's disabled, it goes to the first subdomain in the list of my subdomains, which due to alphabetical ordering is analytics.mydomain.com and I don't really need people stumbling upon my Piwik installation haha

Comment: Oh, in that case redirect them to google :)
`<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName analytics.mydomain.com
 Redirect / https://google.com
</VirtualHost>`

Answer (score 1):

> Name-based virtual hosts for the best-matching set of `<virtualhost>`s are processed in the order they appear in the configuration. The first matching ServerName or ServerAlias is used, with no different precedence for wildcards (nor for ServerName vs. ServerAlias).

source: [Apache HTTP Server Version 2.4 - Using Name-based Virtual Hosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html#using)

Afaik it is not possible to change this sorting process without recompiling.

To change the order of your virtual hosts you could rename the *.conf-files in `/etc/apache/sites-available/` like this:

```
/etc/apache/sites-available/000-default.conf
/etc/apache/sites-available/100-site-one.conf
/etc/apache/sites-available/200-site-two.conf
```

For Debian (Ubuntu should have similar syntax) I recommend to change from lets say `old-site-three.conf` to `300-site-three.conf` in this order:

```
$ sudo a2dissite old-site-three.conf

$ sudo mv /etc/apache/sites-available/old-site-three.conf /etc/apache/sites-available/300-site-three.conf

$ sudo a2ensite 300-site-three.conf

$ sudo apache2ctl configtest

$ sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```

Comment: Thanks. Other than having things in order of conf file names, is there a ways to disable this feature?