# apache disable unconfigured subdomains

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

There is a webserver which has example.com, www.example.com, my.example.com, shop.example.com, static.example.com. 
All sites except www.example.com is on https. 
My problem is when I type randomstring.example.com -> shop.example.com gets served.
But I want nothing to be served. 
For example mail.google.com is a valid subdomain. 
if you type johndoe.google.com you see "This webpage is not available".
How to achieve this via Vhost/.htaccess file.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com/blog/%1 [R=301,L]
```

I hope I helped you.

Comment: Could you please explain the solution. Don't quite understand it

Comment: this post can help you, you just need a default virtual host, for unmatching request http://serverfault.com/questions/82306/apache-default-catch-all-virtual-host