# Apache reverse proxy with HTTPS does not redirect to internal website

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, https

We have installed MyCollab which is a web-based project management system, unfortunately it does not support HTTPS. They say [here](https://community.mycollab.com/docs/hosting-mycollab-on-your-own-server/secure-mycollab-instance/) that the system does not support HTTPS but you can use Apache reverse proxy to redirect https to the internal website.

Now here is my `httpd.conf`

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
ProxyRequests Off

<VirtualHost *:443>
        SSLEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile /root/mysitename.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /root/mysitename.key

        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://server-ip:9000/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://server-ip:9000/
        ServerName localhost
        RewriteEngine On
</VirtualHost>
```

The application is running on port 9000. What happens is, requesting the server IP with HTTPS works fine but it does not redirect me to the internal website, instead it shows the Apache test web page. What am I missing here?

The server has Scientific Linux 7.3 with Apache 2.4.6

Answer (score 1):

If no `ServerName` or `ServerAlias` matches the request, the first `<VirtualHost *:443>` virtual host configuration loaded [will be the default](https://serverfault.com/questions/82306/apache-default-catch-all-virtual-host). You either have another `<VirtualHost *:443>` that actually matches the server IP address or one that comes first in the configuration. That might be directly in your `httpd.conf` or as an include.

On Scientific Linux the configuration file is `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`. Additional configurations are stored in the `/etc/httpd/conf.d/` directory. Probably this directory is included somewhere before your `VirtualHost` configuration.