# can I get guidence with setting up a subdomain?

Tags: ubuntu, web-server, wordpress, subdomain, website

Can someone actually give me the steps on how to create a subdomain and not link me to some random ressources? I have a TLD and run a site on that, but I want create a subdomain for it and install wordpress onto the subdomain. can someone please help me?
**UPDATE**
Would this be correct?

**setting up the database**

1.

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

2.

```
CREATE DATABASE db_name;
```

3.

```
CREATE USER 'user_name'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

4.

```
GRANT ALL ON db_name.* TO 'database_name'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

5.

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

6.

```
EXIT;
```

7.

```
cd /tmp && wget https://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz
```

8.

```
tar -zxvf latest.tar.gz
```

9.

```
sudo mv wordpress /var/www/html/subdomain
```

10.

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/subdomain/
```

11.

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/subdomain/
```

12.

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/subdomain.conf
```

13.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/subdomain/
    ServerName subdomain.domain.com
    ServerAlias www.subdomain.domain.com

<Directory /var/www/html/subdomain/>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

14.

```
sudo a2ensite subdomain.conf
```

15.

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

16.

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```

17.

```
sudo mv /var/www/html/subdomain/wp-config-sample.php   /var/www/html/subdomain/wp-config.php
```

18.

```
sudo nano /var/www/html/subdomain/wp-config.php
```

19.

```
// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'db_name');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'db_username');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'db_password');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

20.
Go To

```
subdomain.domain.com
```

**Is this correct????**

Comment: Hi, please dont repost. A comment on your last question tried to answer you; You need to create the subdomain entry inside your DNS server (godady, etc..) and after in your webserver, if IIS in exemple; you add a website that bind to that subdomain, like subdomain.domain.com > c:\inetpub\folderX, inside that folder you drop the wordpress installation zip. Its done after. If using a linux webserver it’s in the .conf, you add the binding there.

Comment: In big, a webserver will listen to anything, but if the user put a domain inside the request field, like serverfault.com, then the webserver check if it use the default web site folder or use another folder, it depend on your config.

Comment: Check for virtualhost  and the servername directive under apache; a example there https://serverfault.com/questions/82306/apache-default-catch-all-virtual-host

Comment: Mention clearly where your hosting is and where you kept your servers ?

Comment: It is my own server, I'm running an ubuntu apache web server. I would just like to know the steps on how to create a subdomain that doesn't redirect to my main domain

Comment: Using apache, VirtualHost and Servername directive is your answer

Comment: " I have a TLD and run a site on that," No, you do not have a "TLD". TLD is Top Level Domain such as `com`, or `info`. You have a domain name more probably.

Comment: what are you talking about, i do have a TLD, you are actually dumb

Answer (score 1):

First create Virtual host using the below code.

Create a virtual host config file for your domain.

```
   vi  /etc/apache2/sites-available/your_domain.conf
```

Then add the host configuration inside your_domain.conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName your_domain
    ServerAlias www.your_domain
    DocumentRoot /var/www/your_domain
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Then enable the a2ensite for your config file using the command mentioned below.

```
sudo a2ensite your_domain.conf
```

Then check the configurations you made using

```
sudo apache2ctl configtest
```

If the syntax is ok. Then restart the apache,

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

[Still confused check this blog..](https://www.ostechnix.com/configure-apache-virtual-hosts-ubuntu-part-1/)

Comment: hey, thank you. for the 'your_domain' part, could I put a subdomain? I have already set up a website, I'm just looking to create a subdomain for it

Comment: Yep.. Replace with subdomain,

Comment: great! would you by chance know how to install wordpress onto it?

Comment: Sure @BadW01f , Ask as a seperate one,We should not mess with one

Comment: i don't get what you mean... the update I did to the question, is that correct?

Comment: Yeah that correct